# The conversion of the varchar value overflowed an int column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For some value of `@nReservationID`:

```
SELECT @phoneNumber=
  CASE 
    WHEN  ISNULL(rdg2.nPhoneNumber  ,0) = 0 THEN ISNULL(rdg2.nMobileNumber, 0)
    ELSE ISNULL(rdg2.nPhoneNumber  ,0)
  END 
from tblReservation_Details_Guest  rdg2 
where nReservationID=@nReservationID
```

Why do I get this error?

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   USP_CRE_WEB_MEMBER_AUTOGENERATEDECV, Line 136 The conversion of the
>   varchar value '08041159620' overflowed an int column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks Ravi and other users ....
Nevertheless I have got the solution

```
SELECT @phoneNumber=
CASE 
  WHEN  ISNULL(rdg2.nPhoneNumber  ,'0') in ('0','-',NULL)
THEN ISNULL(rdg2.nMobileNumber, '0') 
  WHEN ISNULL(rdg2.nMobileNumber, '0')  in ('0','-',NULL)
THEN '0'
  ELSE ISNULL(rdg2.nPhoneNumber  ,'0')
END 
FROM tblReservation_Details_Guest  rdg2 
WHERE nReservationID=@nReservationID
```

Just need to put '0' instead of 0

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. Without the single quotes you are comparing the integer value, but with the single quotes we compare the strings.

Comment: What is the type of @phoneNumber ?

Comment: Ah, the good old representing a phone number as an integer trip up: Out of interest, may I enquire as to why you would use 0 as a phone number? I ask because 0 isn't a valid number. Why not just leave it as NULL? Does 0 mean anything?

Answer (score 19):

```
Declare @phoneNumber int

select @phoneNumber=Isnull('08041159620',0);
```

Give error :

```
The conversion of the varchar value '8041159620' overflowed an int column.: select cast('8041159620' as int)
```

**AS**

Integer is defined as :

Integer (whole number) data from -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) through 2^31 - 1 (2,147,483,647). Storage size is 4 bytes. The SQL-92 synonym for int is integer.

**Solution**

```
Declare @phoneNumber bigint
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa933198%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried with BIGINT, VARCHAR(100),NVARCHAR(100),TEXT everything, but nothing worked as well. Par reply karne k liye sukria :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make rdg2.nPhoneNumber varchar everywhere instead of int !

Comment: The question does not mention having int column and you can infer from the code that it already is a character type.