# I want to get last year date and current year date but when I run the query output is showing 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactARR]
(
    [PropertyKey] [int] NULL, 
    [Datekey] [numeric](8, 0) NULL, 
    [ARRDate] [date] NULL, 
    [NetRoomRevenue] [numeric](38, 3) NULL, 
    [OccupiedRooms] [numeric](38, 2) NULL, 
    [ARR] [numeric](38, 6) NULL
)
```

And my query: 
[image]

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(ARRDate) = YEAR(getdate()) -1 
               THEN REPLACE (arr, ',', '')
               ELSE 0 
        END) Previous_Year_sum,
    ARRDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(ARRDate) = YEAR(getdate()) 
                THEN REPLACE (arr, ',', '')
                ELSE 0 
        END) current_year
FROM 
    FactARR
GROUP BY 
    ARRDate
ORDER BY
    ARRDate
```

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: Actually what are you trying to do? Please explain clearly with sample table data and expected output.

Comment: ----This is my table 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactARR](
 [PropertyKey] [int] NULL,
 [Datekey] [numeric](8, 0) NULL,
 [ARRDate] [date] NULL,
 [NetRoomRevenue] [numeric](38, 3) NULL,
 [OccupiedRooms] [numeric](38, 2) NULL,
 [ARR] [numeric](38, 6) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: Please format your SQL

Comment: You have a table and a query... but what's the problem? update please??

Comment: Previous_Year_sum ARRDate current_year
0 2001-06-09 0
0 2001-06-10 0
0 2001-06-11 0
0 2001-06-12 0
0 2001-06-14 0
0 2001-06-15 0

Comment: I am getting this error                                     Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The conversion of the varchar value '3461628333' overflowed an int column.

Answer (score 0):

below query result like last year 2015 only.

```
YEAR(getdate()) -1
```

now your below condition like,

```
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(ARRDate) = YEAR(getdate()) -1
```

above condition will equal only 2015 year on ARRDate field. so year 2015 only having value.. remaining year having zero..

**

> you will try below query, using less than . it will take all previous year data. and it works fine.

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(ARRDate) < YEAR(getdate())
```

**

Comment: thanks.. But i am getting ERROR Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The conversion of the varchar value '2290000000' overflowed an int column

Comment: try this, Declare @arr bigint  ... change arr datatype int to bigint

Comment: refer below link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288186/the-conversion-of-the-varchar-value-overflowed-an-int-column)

Comment: this link also (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191472/conversion-of-the-nvarchar-value-3001822585-overflowed-an-int-column)